# How I can install regex package for python 3.4 without errors?

Tags: python, regex

I have a little problem (or a big one?). I want to install regex package
for Python 3.4. But then I use pip or our installation methods I am getting error:

```
universe@universe-AOD270:~/Downloads/regex-2016.04.25$ python setup.py
install --user
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying Python2/regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying Python2/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying Python2/test_regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
running build_ext
building '_regex' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Python2
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Python2/_regex.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Python2/_regex.o
****Python2/_regex.c:46:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.****
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I think that this problem arise because installer try to install this package into Python2.7 directory, but I am not sure. I try pip installation, launch from interpreter of Python, running through terminal, but have no success.
Please, help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just install `python-dev` and `python3-dev`. Although does Python not have a built-in `re` module?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are not talking about the built-in regex (re) module, right?

Comment: There is a regex package as well that mostly difference by being non-greedy by default (if I recall correctly).

Comment: to don.joy - I need regex package because it has in finditer() overlapped flags, finditer() in re modul doesn't have such options. I am taking about a separate package 'regex-2016.04.25'.

Comment: @user423626 Didn't work for Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

I also struggle with this error, then I found the python3-dev is missing but when I run the command it's already installed. Then I check for which python version it is installed using below command -

```
sudo find / -name "Python.h"
```

and output is like -

```
python2.7/Python.h
python3.5/Python.h
```

So then I check the version of python I am running to install that package using below command

```
python3 -V
```

Output -

```
Python 3.6.7
```

So to install python3-dev use below command

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

Just replace it with your python3 or python2 version

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you didn't have `python-dev` or `python3-dev` packages due to your python versoin.

Just install them through 'pip' or 'pip3' package installer and enjoy it!

Note if you find the mentioned packages is installed and your problem is still exist!, you must look for 'Python.h' file in your file system by:

```
sudo find / -name "Python.h"
```

and then add listed paths which includes `Python.h` into your `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable something like:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.6m/
```

and now retry your installation and enjoy!